# How to make XML Design View in Android show accurate design?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

The layout design shown in the XML Design view, in Android Studio, is inaccurate  many times when compared to that seen on an emulator or an actual device.
This is causing problems as a lot of times I can't rely on the XML Design view, and have to put margins etc. by guessing, and then checking on an emulator or an actual device to see if it's appearing there as intended.

I was wondering if there is any tool or something that we can link Android Studio with that can make the XML Design view accurate? If not, is there any way to lessen the hassle of putting the margins by guessing  and checking on an emulator or actual device time and again to reach the point where our design is as intended? Or is there any way we can use the existing design view in a way that it shows the design close to accurately?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: when the app is running on a device or emulator the graphics are rendering, so a lot of times will be diffs from xml Design view. Design view doesn't render the graphic components. I think this is the most accurate you can get. So, most of the times must run the app to see the rendered XMLs

Comment: It's worth noting that the Visual Designer is just a representation (and you can change the parameters) but it's expected you test your layout in real devices.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini How do we change the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar above the visual designer has a device selector where you can use an existing emulator, or even create your own screens with their own densities.

In any case, the idea behind Android Layouts (and iOS interface designer) is that it's a visual representation of a series of constrains (not necessarily related with ConstraintLayout).

You specify your constrains (like: pin to the top, be 100dp wide, etc), and the runtime engine will perform these on the device at runtime, based on the screen size, density, and orientation.

The Visual Designer is an approximation (simplified for speed and efficiency rather than pixel perfection) to guide you into what's going to happen when you run this.

If your layouts are correctly done, the Visual Designer is pretty accurate where it matters (representing your layouts). It's obviously not a replacement for a full engine running on a real device, it would be too slow for now. Maybe in the future it runs on a real emulated environment behind the scenes, but until then... this is what you get.

So to answer your questions: the answer is no, there's no better tool than either the Visual designer or running the project; but the truth is, Android developers that are moderately familiar with the way layouts work in Android, rarely have major issues (in my experience) with the visual designer. It's not a tool I'd rely on to be 100% sure my layout is accurate (it's not), but I know that if something looks extremely broken there, chances are it will be broken at runtime. (there are rare exceptions especially when there's a lot of dynamic stuff happening at runtime that the visual editor has no information or context of), but in these cases you probably already know what you're doing.

If you have specific things that aren't looking as you expect, then perhaps you're "holding it wrong". :) Not to beat a dead horse, but more often than not, everytime we (Android devs) complain about the visual editor in the last couple of years, it was mostly due to our layouts not being 100% correct.

The fact that the android layout engine is so *forgiving* is not always a blessing; I would have preferred a much more strict (if limiting) engine instead of blatantly ignore "wrong" stuff all over the place to maintain backwards compatibility...

Anyway, if you have a *specific* issue, perhaps share more about how you're designing, what you're designing, and what problems you're exactly having.